# Cube changing properties when changing color in Unity 3D with C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an object(sphere) which changes its color on clicking (Blue, Green, Yellow, red). And an another object (cube) which spawn after every 3 seconds and go to collide with the SPHERE but the result will be different depending on the color of the SPHERE. I am using material to change the color of SPHERE.

But I can't find a way to check if CUBE is colliding with SPHERE when it's BLUE or GREEN or YELLOW OR RED.

Comment: why? it shouldn't be hard. What did you try so far?

Comment: It is not hard in 2D as us can set variable for color and create a method to check the current Color of you SPHERE. But we can't do that in 3D. it uses materials.
But I think as we assign color like this
rendCar.sharedMaterial = material[0];
rendCar.sharedMaterial = material[1];

we can check the collision in same way, If the material is [0],[1],[2] or[3].
But I dont know exactly how to do it.

Comment: you cen get your collider info from collision, then get a component of this collider and check its material or index of the array, or any info you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best option would be to set a color variable and change it each time the color changes. Then when your cube hits it just compare the variable. 
The way I change the material is just an easy way for me to do it. You can change it in any way you want just keep the index the same.
You can use this code to do it.

On Sphere

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SpriteCColor : MonoBehaviour {
public Material[] materials;
public Renderer rendBlock;
public int index = 1;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    rendBlock = GetComponent<Renderer>();
    rendBlock.material.SetColor(5, Color.red);

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
   /*
    when index = 
    1 = red
    2 = yellow
    3 = green
    4 = blue
*/
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) { 
        index += 1;
        if (index == materials.Length +1) {
            index = 1;
        }
        //print(index);
        if (index == 1)
        {
            rendBlock.material.SetColor(5, Color.red);
        }
        if (index == 2)
        {
            rendBlock.material.SetColor(5, Color.yellow);
        }
        if (index == 3)
        {
            rendBlock.material.SetColor(5, Color.green);
        }
        if (index == 4)
        {
            rendBlock.material.SetColor(5, Color.blue);
        }


        }


        } 
        }
```

On your Cube you can put this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Senes : MonoBehaviour {
public SpriteCColor A;
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{

  A = collision.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteCColor>();
    if (A.index == 1)
    {
        Debug.Log("Red");
    }
    else if (A.index == 2)
    {
        Debug.Log("Yellow");

    }
    else if (A.index == 3)
    {
        Debug.Log("Green");

    }
    else if (A.index == 4)
    {
        Debug.Log("Blue");

    }

}

}
```

Comment: I tried that but it says UnityEngine.Renderer does not contain defination for color.

Comment: @kichan depending on how you are doing the color if it is a unity named color you could use Material.GetColor. If that doesn't work just set an int to either 1,2,3,4 for each color.

Comment: public Material[] materials;
public Renderer rendBlock;

private int index = 1;

void Start () {
        rendBlock = GetComponent<Renderer>();
        rendBlock.enabled = true;
    }

void Update () {
        if (materials.Length == 0)
        {
            return;
        }
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            index += 1;
            if (index == materials.Length + 1)
            {
                index = 1;
            }
            print(index);
            rendBlock.sharedMaterial = materials[index - 1];
        }
    }

Comment: changing color like this.

Comment: @kichan looking at your code unless you have custom materials you can use rendBlock.material.SetColor(5,Color.red); if you have custom materials you can use your index as it refers to the current color. I have your code modified to work with the first way of you would like to see.

Comment: @kichan I have updated my answer to include a sample code

Comment: Thanks a lot ethan.